# Bug uploading images on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

Can't upload an image to demo the problem. Gray cover blocks the dialog; clicking anywhere makes it all go away.

Comment: reproduced on Windows 7, Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: Reproduced on OS 10.6, Firefox 27.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fixed on the development server. Will be on live site after the next production build.

Thanks for your feedback @jmac

Comment: Just tried it out; works fine!

Comment: This bug is back again...

Comment: What's your browser/os? I don't have this bug on chrome/firefox/safari.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** The same issue is happening on the main Workplace site which is far worse than just no photos on meta. Please fix both at the same time.

The issue may be the Z-index of the background when the dialog pops up. Using the developer tools, I get the following HTML for the gray box:

`<div class="wmd-prompt-background" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 1000; opacity: 0.5; height: 2009px; left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>`

If the z-index is placing it above (rather than behind) the dialog box, we won't be able to click any buttons.

If I manually change the code so that the z-index is 0 the box disappears (probably hidden behind the site background) and I can use the dialog no problem.

So I'm going to guess it's the z-index.