# Grey Box Blocks Reviewing Edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

Much like the [previous issue with image uploads](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/bug-uploading-images-on-meta), a similar grey block is blocking me from reviewing edits entirely.

When I click this:

> [image: Suggested Edit Waiting]

I get this:

> [image: Evil Grey Box]

Any interaction (right or left click) causes the suggested edit review to disappear entirely. The offending grey box according to my developer tools states that it is this div:

`<div style="height: 2355px; display: block;" id="lightbox" class="no-esc-remove"></div>`

Free the suggested edits!

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed. The change will be on live server after our next production build.